# how to call rest api to display data from mysql database into html table

Tags: mysql, node.js, ajax

I want to display data from MySQL database into html table. I write REST API in js file. I try to call in table rows. But it shows error

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 GET localhost:9000/api/addbooks/getbooktable net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```js
var books = function(req, res) {
  const query = 'SELECT * FROM booklist';
  connection.query(query, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    }

    return res.status(200).send(result);
  });
};
```

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:9000/api/addbooks/getbooktable net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 0):

You must import the mysql package first and then make a connection to the mysql database. You seem to be getting started with nodejs and mysql, check out the link below to learn how to connect to mysql through nodejs

Link: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp

Npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Comment: sql connection is ok but not ok to insert data from database  into html table